# error when running project flutter : 'child == _child': is not true

Tags: flutter

I have project which i worked it has been a while and it was correctly running  . Now  i 'm  just running the project and i get this two errors :

```
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6276 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.
E/flutter ( 9693): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element
```

i tried to do flutter clean and flutter pub get but still the same issue
what is the problem ?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the issue ?

Comment: it is a whole project and i don't know in which file had the issue

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: exactly that what i did but it did not work

Comment: Sorry, can't help until I got [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to play with

Comment: Does this answer your question?(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64257)

Comment: Please run the project with verbose flag, `flutter run --verbose` and share detailed error log